# Pointer initialization with an arbitrary number

Tags: c, pointers

```
{
    int *p=12;
    printf("%p",p);
    printf("\n%d",p);
}
```

OUTPUT:

0000000C

12

Question: So is p assigned the address 0x0000000C?

```
{ 
    int *p=12;
    *p=22;
}
```

But this one doesn't run. So what's actually happening?

Comment: I think it's just the representation which is throwing you off... It's hex... it goes 0x0 - 0x9, 0xA = 10, 0xB = 11, 0xC = 12 So what exactly is your question after understanding this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int *p=12;
```

This declares a pointer and sets the address to which it points to `12`.

```
*p=22;
```

This de-references the pointer and writes 22 to the `int` at that  memory address `12`. Since you did not allocate any memory and just set the pointer to point at a random address, it results in a runtime error.

What is confusing you is that both pieces of code contain `*p=...`. However, the first assignment is to the pointer, and the second assignment is to the pointee. This is just one of those notational overloadings that you have to get used to when programming in C.

Comment: so in the first case, shouldn't printf("%d",*p) return garbage? but the program crashes.

Comment: As the answer states, reading memory you don't have access to will generate a runtime error. If you *could* read it, then yes, you'd probably see garbage.

Comment: Ok, final query. Is this statement correct: the pointer can point to this random address because the pointer definition is valid, and hence it is allocated memory to store this address, but no value can be stored at this address because memory at this address is not allocated by the compiler (much like using undefined variables).

Answer (score 0):

Both cases have undefined behavior.

- The behavior of the first example is undefined, as you use an invalid pointer.
- The second example is worst, as you **derefernce** a pointer with invalid address.

  ```
  int *p=12; // set the address 12 to the int pointer called p
  *p=22;     // set the value 22 to the address 12 (invalid address)
  ```

Comment: He is pointing to 12, so long as he uses that correctly then there is nothing wrong with this.... (IMHO)

Comment: he is not pointing to 12, he has a pointer with the value 12 (pointing to address 12)

Comment: I beg to disagree... &p will not be 12.... The address is not 12.... He points to the value 12 with the de-reference of the address (pointer)....

Comment: @Jay - I think we just use different words for the same thing. a pointer contains an address. that's its content, so p contains the address 12.

Comment: Good Call... Damn engrish... thatz my bad